# Google Sheets - getData() returns an error as not defined

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

So i am using the following code to copy a query into a spreadsheet. When i run the code it gives me ReferenceError: getData is not defined.

if i try the same code  on another google sheets document it runs smoothly and copies everything

```
function importdataNPS() {

let data = getData("https://popsql.com/share/queries/···/last_run.csv?access_token=...");

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('·····').getSheetByName('Real_NPS_Q4'); 

sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),data[0].length +1).clearContent();
if ( data.length == 0){ return; }
sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

What am I doing wrong? is there an authorization for the google sheet?

Comment: Check your other spreadsheet for function getData(...).  If the spreadsheet you are executing importdataNPS() does not have that function defined it will not run.

Comment: getData() is a predefined function from google scripts, not a function i created

Comment: as in it´s not defined in either of the two sheets explicitly

Comment: I don't know of any predefined script functions.  If I try to run getData() I get the same error.  There are only predefined javascript functions and getData() ain't one of them.

Comment: you were right, the function had been run the other code and afterwards deleted, so it was already there defined but i coldnt see it in the code